# Не могу подключить ssh-ключ

Tags: git, bitbucket

Вроде уже не первый год пользуюсь гитом и битбакетом в частности, но до сих пор возникают проблемы при первичной настройке... Вот сейчас например хоть убей не пушится в репозиторий. Делаю все по офф [инструкции](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh3SetupSSHwithSourcetreeonWindows): ключи сгенерировал, в bitbucket добавил, в Pageant добавил, пытаюсь запушить в репозиторий (я в нем админ) - пишет что "не удалось пройти аутентификацию по ssh-ключу - сервер отклонил соединение". Что за бред? Ну как такое может быть?

Comment: Каждую среду у bitbucket техобслуживание

Comment: @Insider так проблема в этом? Ну ничего себе... А я мучался. (=_=) Ну посмотрим завтра как оно будет.

Comment: @Insider как-бы не так. Я все еще не могу запушить. Похоже проблема не в этом.

Comment: Какой программой вы пытаетесь запушить?

Comment: @Insider их же SourceTree.

Comment: хм.. с ним у меня тоже проблемы, а через сторонний софт, нормально все.

Comment: @Insider а когда добавляю реп по https все нормально... (вход по логину/паролю) И не с одним репом так. Вообще bitbucket&sourcetree с ssh не дружат. :(